# Is there any virtual drive for Windows that supports compression?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtual-drive

I refer to mount it under Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for 
http://www.winmount.com/

Which allows you to /mount/ compressed files like RAR, ZIP, etc. as drives.

However, that is not a free program.